# Problem getting value of counter from Firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the value of a counter, and setting it to my model ID, using a Firebase database.

The connection to the database is working and other methods are too. Now I'm trying to not have to manually set the ID for my model every time I need to add a new item.

The problem is that the ValueEventListener that is supposed to retrieve the ID is not working, meaning that the app is not "entering" that piece of code.

```java
invia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Data data = new Data();
        FirebaseDatabase database2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef2 = database2.getReference("Counter/node");
        myRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Counter counter = dataSnapshot.getValue(Counter.class);
                data.setId(String.valueOf(counter.getCnt_android() + 1));
            }

            @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });

        data.setUser(user.getText().toString());
        data.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Information Android/");
        myRef.child(data.getId()).setValue(data);

        Counter cnt_android = new Counter();
        cnt_android.setCnt_android(Integer.parseInt(data.getId()));
        myRef2.child("cnt_android").setValue(cnt_android);
    }
});
```

I've tried putting this two lines:

```java
data.setUser(user.getText().toString());
data.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
```

Inside the onDataChange to see if it's a problem from getting the counter value but it's not because they remain null, even if I give them from the EditBoxes inside the app, so I'm starting to think that there's a problem with that specific code.

The app crashes on this line:

```java
myRef.child(data.getId()).setValue(data);
```

because there is no value for the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase `onDataChange()` is asynchronous, which means the compiler will move to the next task, and then when `onDataChange()` retrieves all the data it will be executed.

In your case, after `onDataChange()`, you have the following code:

```
 myRef.child(data.getId()).setValue(data);
```

This is getting executed before `onDataChange()`, therefore `data.getId()` is returning null.

To solve your problem, you need to add your code inside `onDataChange()`:

```
    myRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Counter counter = dataSnapshot.getValue(Counter.class);
            data.setId(String.valueOf(counter.getCnt_android() + 1));
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Information Android/");
            myRef.child(data.getId()).setValue(data);

        }

        @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });
```